# Can web app automatically update when I duplicate the sheet which contains the webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-apps

I have a email Campaign sheet where I can track the email status, if its opened or not. But When I duplicate this sheet, I will have to deploy the webapp again and update the img src link. I am Using doGet function to capture the tracking pixel.

Is there a way I this can update automatically when I duplicate the sheet containing Web App?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- add this img tag -->
    <img src="https://script.google.com/a/verzeo.in/macros/s/AKfycbwNQXBUmr6TovUxqdkz_ZAptyJZu7ZsvncmU12L/exec?method=track&email=<?= email ?>" width="0" height="0"> 

    Hi <?= name ?>. We are testing our beta features for email marketing.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There’s a good reason not to enable images haphazardly

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot. The reason for that is because you cannot get the script that is bound to another file. There is [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037) that asks for that to be added (click the star ☆ to let Google know that you want this).

Having that, it would be a simple thing to do since there already is an API to make deployments ([see Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)); so you could make a script that makes the copy and deploys the bound script for you. But until then, you are out of luck.

Comment: Personally I hope they never resolve issue because it Just empowers these trackers to track us even more prolifically than they can now. Please take note of what this is doing the end-user gets absolutely no benefit from this image because it zero height and zero width

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- add this img tag -->
    <img src="https://script.google.com/a/verzeo.in/macros/s/AKfycbwNQXBUmr6TovUxqdkz_ZAptyJZu7ZsvncmU12L/exec?method=track&email=<?= email ?>" width="0" height="0"> 

    Hi <?= name ?>. We are testing our beta features for email marketing.
  </body>
</html>
```